# “Use of undefined constant” how to fix replace in all files

Tags: regex, php-7.2

I have very old php4-5 project that needs to migrate to php7.2

It has a lot of codes like:

```
echo '<img src="img/'.$r[imgurl1].'"
strip_tags($r[details])
```

It's now in my local ubuntu 18 apache&php-server.
How can i search and replace all the .php files to add quotes ?
I cannot add doublequotes if [] contains $ (Variable) sign in it, of course
And also if it already contains " or '

I know little bit of preg, but not enough.. 
I have sublime text3 and notepad++ that can do also replaces if only now the right regular expression. Pleas help!

Answer (score 1):

## Using Notepad++

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\$\w+\[\K([^$"'\]]+)`
- Replace with: `"$1"`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\$              # $ sign
\w+             # 1 or more word characters
\[              # opening square bracket
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
(               # start group 1
    [^$"'\]]+   # 1 or more any character that is not $, ", ', ]
)               # end group
```

**Given:**

```
echo '<img src="img/'.$r[imgurl1].'"
strip_tags($r[details])
$abc = $def[$xxx]
```

**Result for given example:**

```
echo '<img src="img/'.$r["imgurl1"].'"
strip_tags($r["details"])
$abc = $def[$xxx]
```

## Using php

```
$in = <<<'EOD'
echo '<img src="img/'.$r[imgurl1].'"
strip_tags($r[details])
$abc = $def[$xxx]
EOD;
$res = preg_replace('/\$\w+\[\K([^$"\'\]]+)/', '"$1"', $in);
echo $res;
```

**Output:**

```
echo '<img src="img/'.$r["imgurl1"].'"
strip_tags($r["details"])
$abc = $def[$xxx]
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, this helped thanks!
It also matches to $array[12], meaning numbers get quoted too.
Found out from irc that this was working solution:

```
\[(\w*[A-Za-z]\w*)\]

substitution: ["\1"]
```